# Prisma - Where selector on type with two unique fields

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I'm trying to implement resolver which will check if the user with given login exists in the database. But I have a hard time with where selector in Prisma.

So I have the type User:

```js
type User {
  UserID: ID! @id
  Login: String! @unique
  Password: String!
  Phone: String!
  Mail: String!
  Comments: [Comment!]
    @relation(
      name: "AllCommentsOfUser"
      fields: [UserID]
      references: [CommentID]
    )
  Likes: [Like!]
    @relation(name: "AllLikesOfUser", fields: [UserID], references: [LikeID])
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
}
```

This is the query generated by Prisma

```js
user(where: UserWhereUniqueInput!): User

input UserWhereUniqueInput {
  UserID: ID
  Login: String
}
```

In the login function am trying to check if the user with given login exist in my database:

```js
  async login(parent, { email, password, username }, ctx, info) {
      const user = await ctx.prisma.user({ username }); // Option 1 
      const user = await ctx.prisma.user({ Login: username }); // Option 2 

      if (!user) {
        throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${username}`);
      }

      const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!valid) {
        throw new Error("Invalid password");
      }

      return {
        token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET),
        user,
      };
    },
  },
```

Each time I'm ending up with following error message:

> You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on User. Please provide exactly one unique field and value.